# Tween duration affected by textfield length

Tags: actionscript-3

I am using tween with easing to horizontally scroll a dynamic textfield from right to left in as3. The fixed  stage dimension is 720 x 576. The program works with the preset duration for small text field length, but if the text field length becomes greater than 720, the tween speed becomes too fast.I use a bitmap to estimate the width of the text field since the font is also loaded at runtime. Please suggest some solutions. Here's a code snipet.

```
  var text_:textfield = new textfield();
  text_.text = "Hello";
  addChild(text_);
  var myTween:Tween = new Tween(text_, "x", Normal.easeOut, 720, 0, 400, true);
```

Comment: Use TextField.textWidth property.

Comment: I don't understand the problem then. Calculate tweening duration based on text width.

Comment: Textfield with long text are  animated faster than shorter ones.

Comment: What is the acceptable top speed? Set a max speed value and use a math minimum value method (Math.min I believe) to always set the speed to the lower of the two values. Without you posting some code, I can't be any more specific than that since I don't feel like writing my own program that does what you describe.

Comment: Question edited to include a code snippet. Speed will be kept variable between 100 to 1000.

Comment: That's what "calculate" for. If tweening speed will be inversely related to the text width (e.g. tweening duration in milliseconds equal to text width in pixels) then visible speed will be the same for any text length.

Comment: Thanks Organis for the inputs. Thats what I expected - visible speed should remain same, but speed is varying considerably for much longer text.

Answer (score 1):

the way of getting a `Textfield` width, is `mytextfield.textWidth`

you must declare a Constant Millisecond for duration per a certain width (or per single letter)
then simply divide the values and get a true rate for Duration of the tween.